# How do I use a negative number?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was working on a little project in the Unity game engine. I was doing something with `transform.position`, until I ran into a problem. I needed to use a negative number for the z coordinates, but whenever I use a negative number,

> I the following error: error CS0119: Expression denotes a type', where
>   a variable', value' or method group' was expected

So I lead to the conclusion that there was a problem with a negative number. I couldn't find anything related to this, so I decided to ask a question. Here is part of my code:

```
transform.position = Vector3(32.23805f, 0.4999998f, -17.32514f);
```

Comment: You forgot the `new` keyword.

Comment: The very first sentance of the tag [tag:unity] is *"DO NOT USE ON QUESTIONS ABOUT THE UNITY GAME ENGINE (use: [tag:unity3d] instead)"*

Answer (score 9):

This isn't a problem with using negative values.  You are missing the "new" keyword.

Try this:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(32.23805f, 0.4999998f, -17.32514f);
```

Answer (score 1):

when not using the ***new*** keyword, the compiler would assume that you are trying to declare a **type** of a variable **instead** of assigning a value to the **trasform.position** variable.
that is why you are getting the error

> Expression denotes a type', where a variable', value' or method group' was expected

just add the  **new** keyword and it should work.